# Sum of values spread across tables in document? (like in Word)

Tags: tables, calculations

My document is structured as follows:

```
* Bla bla bla

  Quantity | Item     | Price per item | Total price
  ---------+----------+----------------+------------
         5 | Sandwich |           5.00 |       25.00


* More bla bla bla

  Quantity | Item     | Price per item | Total price
  ---------+----------+----------------+------------
         3 | Coke     |           1.00 |        3.00

Grand total: 28.00
```

In the past, I have created a similar document with Word 2007 where I had all
calculations done automatically. *Is that also possible with LaTeX?*

I am aware of [spreadtab](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab), which I frequently use for invoices. It
works great if all the values are in one table. However, this is not the
case here.

Comment: You could consider using an implementation that uses [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool). See, for example, [How to cherry pick from `datatool` DB and calculate totals](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125044/5764). Of course, there is also [How can I automatically calculate sums in a LaTeX table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3851/5764)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\def\q#1{\gdef\thisq{#1}#1}
\def\p#1{\gdef\thisp{#1}#1}
\def\total{0}
\makeatletter
\def\itemcost{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\thisp\p@*\thisq\relax
  \xdef\total{\strip@pt\dimexpr\total\p@+\thisp\p@*\thisq\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

 Bla bla bla

\begin{tabular}{rcrr}
  Quantity & Item     & Price per item & Total price\\
\hline
       \q{5} & Sandwich &           \p{5.00} &  \itemcost
\end{tabular}


 More bla bla bla

\begin{tabular}{rcrr}
  Quantity & Item     & Price per item & Total price\\
\hline
         \q{3} & Coke     &           \p{1.00} &     \itemcost
\end{tabular}

Grand total: \total

\end{document}
```

---

If you are using `tabularx` you need to only do the arithmetic on the final run, not when it is doing trial runs to calculate the widths.

```
\def\q#1{\gdef\thisq{#1}#1}
\def\p#1{\gdef\thisp{#1}#1}
\def\total{0}
\makeatletter
\let\normalwrite\write
\def\itemcost{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\thisp\p@*\thisq\relax
  \ifx\write\normalwrite\xdef\total{\strip@pt\dimexpr\total\p@+\thisp\p@*\thisq\relax}\fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

Comment: This looks great, only I get an *"Arithmetic overflow."* error if the amount of sandwiches is increased from 5 to 5000. Is there any way to make it work with large numbers?

Comment: It uses dimen arithmetic so maximum value 16384, Your examples used .00 if you only ever need integer values you could use `\numexpr` instead and remove the `\p@` or you could use a floating point package (`fp` or `l3fp`)

Comment: With the `fp` package, it works fine, except that if I use `tabularx`, then `\total` is off by a factor of three (see [related  question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95160)). So, while your reply answers my question to the point, I am now having a closer look at the suggestion by @Corto.

Comment: @feklee it could be more than three, depending how many trials tx does: see update

Comment: That does the trick!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution the takes advantage of some tricks available through `pgfmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=2,
         /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true}
\def\grandtotal{0}
\def\getgrandtotal{\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\grandtotal}\$\pgfmathresult}
%% #1=quantity
%% #2=description
%% #3=price per item
\def\receipt#1#2#3{%%
  \par
  \vspace{1.25\baselineskip}
  \begin{tabular}{cp{1.5in}rr}
  Quantity & Item & Price per item & Total price \\\hline
  #1       & #2   & \$#3             & 
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#3}\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}\$\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\grandtotal}{\pgfmathresult+\grandtotal}%%
  \xdef\grandtotal{\grandtotal}%%      
  \end{tabular}
  \vspace{1.25\baselineskip}
  \par
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Some random text.

\receipt{5}{Sandwich}{5.00}

Some more random text.

\receipt{3}{Coke}{1.00}

Grand total: \getgrandtotal

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

After seeing your comments about `Arithmetic overflow`, here's a variation on the above `pgfmath` approach which uses the `fp` package together with `siunitx` to make the numbers more readable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\grandtotal{0}
\def\currentAmount{}
\def\dollars#1{\SI[per-mode=symbol,group-separator={,}]{#1}[\$]{}}
\def\getgrandtotal{\dollars{\grandtotal}}
%% #1=quantity
%% #2=description
%% #3=price per item
\def\receipt#1#2#3{%%
  \par
  \vspace{1.25\baselineskip}
  \begin{tabular}{cp{1.5in}rr}
  Quantity & Item & Price per item & Total price \\\hline
  #1       & #2   & \dollars{#3}   & 
    \FPmul\currentAmount{#1}{#3}%%
    \FPround\currentAmount{\currentAmount}{2}%%
    \dollars{\currentAmount}%%
    \FPadd\grandtotal{\currentAmount}{\grandtotal}%%
    \FPround\grandtotal{\grandtotal}{2}%%
    %% make the `\grandtotal` available outside of environment.
    \xdef\grandtotal{\grandtotal}%%      
  \end{tabular}
  \vspace{1.25\baselineskip}
  \par
}

\begin{document}

Some random text.

\receipt{5}{Sandwich}{5.00}

Some more random text.

\receipt{3}{Coke}{1.00}

Some more random text.

\receipt{300}{Something expensive}{16179.52}

Grand total: \getgrandtotal

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\STsavecell` macro of the spreadtab package. This macro permit to use the numerical value of a cell outside of the table.

Update

After seeing the comment of @cgnieder, I add an example based on the provided MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

 Bla bla bla


\begin{spreadtab}[%
  \STsavecell\TotFood{d2}]{{tabular}{cccc}}
  @Quantity & @Item     & @Price per item & @Total price\\
\hline
       5 & @Sandwich &           5 & a2*c2
\end{spreadtab}


 More bla bla bla

\begin{spreadtab}[%
  \STsavecell\TotBevreage{d2}]{{tabular}{cccc}}
  @Quantity & @Item     & @Price per item & @Total price\\
\hline
       3 & @Coke &           1 &  a2*c2
\end{spreadtab}

\FPadd{\foo}{\TotFood}{\TotBevreage}
\FPclip{\result}{\foo}
Grand total: \FPprint{\result}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea. Would you mind adding an example based on the MWE provided in the question?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to have some kind of automation, the easiest way is to achieve this outside of TeX or LaTeX.  You typically store your tabular data in some external file that you process with an ad-hoc program which writes your dynamical data to one or more auxilary files that you `\input` in your document.

If you are working on a *NIX system and have some programming skill (even rudimentary), this is very easy to achieve, mostly because TeX input files are plain text files.  With AWK or any of your favourite languages, you can do most of the work in a few minutes, so you can decently ask somebody to help you if you cannot do it yourself.

If you are working on another system, the same approach is probably possible, but you may first need to install an interpreter or a compiler for your favourite language.